# Starting point for creating installer using izpack 5 and maven

Tags: java, maven, build, izpack

I already have Maven creating an assembly widget1.0-distribution.zip containing:

```
widget-1.0
widget-1.0/lib/widget.jar
widget-1.0/lib/3rdpartyjar1.jar
widget-1.0/lib/3rdpartyjar2.jar
widget-1.0/widget.sh
widget-1.0/widget.properties
widget-1.0/widget.exe
widget-1.0/widget.ini
```

Now I just want to use Izpack 5 to create an installer which allows the user to decide where to simply install the widget application, maintaining the same folder structure.

Ive used Izpack 4.3.5 before but what im struggling with is getting started with integrating this with maven, I have created my install.xml but cannot see how this plugins in to the maven pom.xml

Answer (score -1):

The IzPack wiki has quite a detailed page on how to build an Izpack 5 Installer with maven: https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IZPACK/Compiling+Using+Maven

Is there anything you miss?

Comment: It seems incredibly complex, Im sure most of that isn't neccessary but its very difficult to ses how to build a simpler case.

Comment: Quite honestly there is not much you can leave out from this process besides the part about custom panel.

Comment: Yet once Ive created an install.xml I can build a complete izpack installation in one stage using compile.bat ?

Comment: Since codehaus is gone - the links are here: http://web.archive.org/web/20150508091543/http://izpack.codehaus.org/izpack-maven-plugin/#usage.html and here: http://web.archive.org/web/20141028070616/http://svn.codehaus.org/izpack-svn/izpack-maven/trunk/izpack-maven-plugin/src/it/sample/pom.xml

Comment: There is a new documentation site available: https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IZPACK/. I changed the links in my answer accordingly